# How do i store a Stopwatch() time in an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, stopwatch

Im trying to make a very messed up leader board system and i need to store a stopwatch time in a int[] array. I want to output them all using a for loop system to output Name, Age, House and Time in ms, I've already converted it to ms its mainly just putting it into the array which is the problem.

however everything i try keeps telling me that it cant convert the system.diagnostics.stopwatch to int[].
Theres probably an easy solution or easier way to make the leader board so any help would be appreciated.

Bulk of the code where the problem is:

```
Console.WriteLine("Starting . . .");
            randNum = rd.Next(65, 91);
            letter = (char)randNum;
            //generate random number which corresponds to a letter and store it

            randum2 = rd.Next(1, 5000);

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(randum2);
            Time.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine(letter);
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            letter1 = Console.ReadLine();

            if (letter1 == letter.ToString())
            {
                Time.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
                Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed: {0}", Time.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + name);
                Console.WriteLine("Age: " + age);
                Console.WriteLine("House: " + House);
                Console.WriteLine(" ");

            }
            for(int i = 0; i > totalplayers; i++)
            {

                namescore[totalplayers] = name;
                Housescore[totalplayers] = House;
                
                timescore[totalplayers] = Time;

            }
```

The Leader Board System:

```
else if (choice == "Leaderboard")
                     {
                       
                Console.WriteLine();
                        for(int i = 0; i > totalplayers; i++)
                        {
                    
                        Console.WriteLine(name[i] + "  " + House[i] + "  "+ timescore[i]+"ms" );
                    
                     }
                        
                     }
```

Comment: Add code as text, not image.

Comment: that would have been smart... ill go do that now

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to store the StopWatch object itself in the `int` array.  That won't work.  Either change the array to `StopWatch[]`, or store the elapsed milliseconds from the StopWatch object into your `int` array.

Comment: Stopwatch class has a TimeSpan property `Elapsed`. Then to get the milliseconds you can just use the `TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds`.

Comment: `timescore[totalplayers] = Time;` <== Yep, that won't fly. I'd suggest to make that a `TimeSpan[]` and store `Time.Elapsed`.

Comment: ^^ btw: that should probably either be `timescore[i]` ? or the for loop is totally superfluent here.

Answer (score 0):

To store elapsed time in an int you would do

```
timescore[totalplayers] = (int)Time.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

But there are several other problems in your code. First of all you probably wanted set the timescore for each player, i.e.

```
timescore[i] = (int)Time.ElapsedMilliseconds;
```

Also, converting the time to an int loses information, you will have less precision, but perhaps just as important, you no longer can use the type system to know what unit the time describes. Milliseconds? Seconds? Ticks? Without specifically checking the assignment you have no idea. So it would be better to keep it as a TimeSpan, that would make the unit unambiguous, i.e.

```
timescore[i] = Time.Elapsed;
```

Setting the time in a loop like you do, just after you have started the timer, would very likely just result in a zero timescore for each player. It is difficult to tell from your example if this is correct behavior or not.